# Potential equation for large scale particles

Tags: potential, coulombs-law

I am reading J.Carrier 1988 paper called "A FAST ADAPTIVE MULTIPOLE ALGORITHM FOR PARTICLE SIMULATIONS" which states that the potential according to coulomb's law is equal to -log(||x-x0||).

I wanted to know isn't it supposed to be kqQ/r? how did it turn to -log(||x-x0||) http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/greengar/cgr_88.pdf page 2 equation 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're working in two dimensions.  In two dimensions, the differential version of Gauss's law leads to that potential.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that long, straight wire geometries act as 2D systems when nearer the wire than the ends/